# store a string into a variable using sed/awk from a txt file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Hi i have the below text file = id.txt

```
xid: indv1000 id: indv12482
xid: SC25986 id: artf220747
xid: 1000 id: tracker4164
xid: indn1001 id: indn1028
xid: proj1234 id: proj12045
```

I need to fetch the "proj12045" from the above file and store that into a variable. And this will be done for multiple text files and the projID can be in any row

Is this possible using sed/awk

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code produced by you? Any error message? Which is your expected output?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. i dont have any idea on sed/awk, i just need the command or logic on how to parse the txt file and fetch the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the second attempt:

```
awk 'match($0,/proj[0-9]{5}/){ x = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }END{ print x }'
```

This time your input is screened using the match function which is searching in each line for the string "proj" followed by five letters. If a match occurs the substr functions cuts out only the match and assigns it to the variable x. After the program finishes x is printed. If proj is not always the searched string you have to adjust the regex to that.

Comment: the "proj12045" , this changes in other text files

Comment: Ok, this so the proj12045 change from file. Do you have a list of these ID's in a second file ore are you not knowing them?

Comment: This is a process, i have a forklift binary which creates these text fields for different inputs. So the ID will be changing

Comment: But is there any structure to the ID? Will it allways be four letters followed by five digits or is there anything the ID's have in common?

Comment: Changed my answer. I hope this one works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/proj[0-9]*/s/.* id: //p' id.txt
```